# Does a very big JBoss server.log file affect performance?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am unsure of how the JBoss server.log file is appended to, but does it affect performance if JBoss appends to an already large server.log file? E.g. a 1GB file as opposed to a 10MB file?

Comment: In my case when i work a lot of time on jboss i gives me the errors of `OutOfMemoryError : PermGen space`  that's why i delete the folders : `log` , `tmp` and the content of `data\content`.
Then i delete the deployed app from standalone.xml => deployement.
Then to make all this allows my server)to start correctly.

Comment: sure, but does the actual server.log log file size affect performance if it gets too big? There is also an option to start a new log file after a certain MB threshold limit has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes. It has nothing to do with JBoss though. Any time you have a large file on the filesystem, the operating system has to start allocating new segments on the disk to keep the file growing. This makes the file really fragmented. Any read operations will be affected as well. I suggest you lookup the recommended max file sizes for your OS.